# Metapost figures with ttf fonts via XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, metapost, truetype

I use Metapost to create pdf figures to include in the book I am writing. I usually create pdf files with the command `TEX=latex mpost figure.mp` and then I convert the output files `figure.1`, `figure.2` to pdf. I am not interested in integrating Metapost directly in my main files, I am confortable with managing separate pdf files and include them `\includegraphics{figure-1.pdf}` etc.

However, I would like to use in the figures labels the same (.ttf) fonts I use for my text. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to instruct Metapost to use the xetex engine to create labels, provided that this is possible.

Comment: yes, use `luamplib` and `lualatex` and `standalone.cls`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a suggested workflow that you might like to adopt.  It involves using `lualatex` with the `luamplib` package to create PDF files directly from your Metapost source.

1. I am assuming you have an MP source file called `figure.mp` that contains two `beginfig()/endfig` pairs that produces `figure-1.mps` and `figure-2.mps` which you convert to PDF.
2. Split this file up into two separate files using this template.

   ```
    \documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
    \usepackage{luamplib}
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{<whatever TTF font you are using with XeLateX>}
    \begin{document}
    \mplibtextextlabel{enable}
    \begin{mplibcode}
    beginfig(1);
      <your MP code here>
    endfig;
    \end{mplibcode}
    \end{document}
   ```
3. Name the files `figure-1.mp` and `figure-2.mp`.  (Strictly speaking, the files are LaTeX source files, so you might want to use `.tex` extension, but I prefer to use `.mp` because that makes my editor load the correct syntax colouring).
4. Compile them with `lualatex figure-1.mp` and `lualatex figure-2.mp` to create `figure-1.pdf` and `figure-2.pdf`
5. Include them in your book with `\includegraphics{figure-1}` and `\includegraphics{figure-2}`

`lualatex` supports `fontspec` in exactly the same way as `xelatex`.

I've written a lot more about this workflow and working with `luamplib` in my [notes on Drawing with Metapost](https://github.com/thruston/Drawing-with-Metapost) which you might like to read.  In particular, you might find section 3.2 and section 12 useful.

### Notes

- **Syntax highlighting** -- using this idea means that the source files are Metapost, wrapped up in LaTeX.  This will confuse most syntax highlight engines in most editors.  It is *possible* in Vim highlighting to define different rules for different regions of a file, so you could define the `mplibcode` environment as a Metapost region in a LaTeX file, but I have found it tricky to do this reliably.  My solution is just to force MP syntax highlight for the whole file by using an `.mp` suffix and setting up the appropriate file type trigger.  In Vim you can also force this by doing `set ft mp` explicitly.
- **Common LaTeX code** -- If you have a common set of LaTeX code to share among all your MP source files, then you should probably put all the common elements into a shared file and then include this in each MP source file.  For my "Drawing with Metapost" project, I put some common colour and listings definitions into a style file called `dwmpcode.sty`, and then I have `\usepackage{dwmpcode}` at the top of my main document and at the top of any MP drawings that need to use the common definitions
- **Common Metapost code** -- If you have a common set of *Metapost* code to share among all your MP source files, then it's a bit simpler. Put all the common code into a Metapost source file, perhaps "my-common-code.mp" and then add `input my-common-code` as the first line of the `mplibcode` environment in each source file.

Comment: Great, thank you! I only have a problem with this solution: often my figures are related and share some variable or code. How can I do if I separate figures into separate .tex files? A second (possibly minor) problem is that by embedding the code into a latex file I cannot benefit from metapost syntax highlighting. Working in a single .mp file is much more comfortable, but I understand that we cannot have everything, can we?

Comment: This was very useful. In meanwhile, I adapted the workflow for use within `org-mode` (in Emacs), so that each figure is compiled through `org-babel` (it required a bit of hacking and programming, but not so difficult). This solution also allowed me to have syntax highlighting and common code. Thanks agains, this will be a major improvement in my use of Metapost